# Check if dataset contains a specific value

Tags: vb.net, dataset

How can i check if a dataset contains a specific value? It's crazy that no one has done this before. Couldn't find it on the net!!!

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "contains a specific value"? Do you mean whether or not a value is present in any row in any column in any table?

Comment: Ya, that's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean go through the entire dataset tables, columns and rows?

Here is something that could help you:

```
Dim valueToSearch as String = "some text"
For Each dTable As DataTable In ds.Tables
    For Each dRow As DataRow In dTable.Rows
        For index As Integer = 0 To dTable.Columns.Count - 1
            Convert.ToString(dRow(index)).Contains(valueToSearch)
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: that's exactly what I mean, although its a very very smal dataset. Shouldn't take that long. So how is this done? I still havent found anything on the net!!!

Comment: Datasets hold tables, each table holds rows, each row holds items. In Darkxes example you would check drow(index) for the specific value you are looking for. If you know the exact column it will be in you can skip the inner most loop, and just check dRow("columnname") for your value.

Comment: i know the table name, but where do i check for the string im looking for? dRow("colmnname").Contains(string) would be my first guess, but 'contains' doenst excist in that context.

Comment: You can index directly against a datarow to retreive the stored value. See the msdn article for the DataRow object.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx

Answer (score 3):

**Suppose I have Dataset DsStu containing Table Student with Columns [Rollno,Name,Branch].**

**Case 1** *I want Name of student whose Rollno is 15*.

```
     Dim answer As String = ""
     Dim SerchRows() As Data.DataRow
     SerchRows = DsStu.Tables(0).Select("Rollno = '15'") 
     answer = ""

     For k As Integer = 0 To SerchRows.Length - 1
       If answer = "" then  
          answer = SerchRows(k).Item("Name")
       Else
          answer = answer & Vbnewline & SerchRows(k).Item("Name")
       End If
     Next

     MsgBox(" " & answer)
```

**Case 2** *I want Name of all student whose Rollno is greater than equal to 15 and Branch is Electrical.*

```
     Dim answer As String = ""
     Dim SerchRows() As Data.DataRow

     SerchRows = DsStu.Tables(0).Select("Rollno >= '15' And Branch = 'Electrical'") 
     answer = ""

     For k As Integer = 0 To SerchRows.Length - 1
       If answer = "" then  
          answer = SerchRows(k).Item("Name")
       Else
          answer = answer & Vbnewline & SerchRows(k).Item("Name")
       End If
     Next

     MsgBox(" " & answer)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a BindingSource use the "Find" method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158165.aspx

So if it returns -1 it's not there and otherwise it will return the position.

Comment: first of all, the question has been asked and answered like a decade ago. Second, you're posting a link which is about .NET version 4.5 (there was no 4.5 back in 2010). And 3rd, you're down voting me for your disability to read!?

Comment: Hey bro, I don't know what are you upset about :) I was searching online for the same question so I came across this page and others, and when I found a better solution I added it here so other people searching like me would find it. And I didn't down vote you :/

Comment: I'm not upset. The down vote came along with your post on the exact same minute. Kinda suspicious. Not that I care much about it, but still kinda weird to get a down vote because i wasn't working in the future with the future's .net framework you used.